# Parameter constraints while applying custom rules

Tags: rules-engine

I am trying to implement a custom rule in Sitecore 9.1

Thankfully it is working fine.

I want to put a condition that the user is able to provide an integer value. Please advise on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the `Day of Month` rule.

It's a built-in rule in Sitecore (`/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Date/Day of Month`)

Its `Text` field says:

```
when the current day of the month [operatorid,Operator,,compares to] [DayNumber,Integer,,number]
```

The `[DayNumber,Integer,,number]` part is for user input.

It means:

- `DayNumber` - it's the property in the condition class to which the value will be assigned
- `Integer` - it's the name of the macro - that's what you're asking for. Macros are stored under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Macros` node. `Integer` macro will allow only numbers.
- `number` it's the placeholder text in the condition when the value is not entered yet.

You can do similar rule on your own and use `Integer` macro for your values.

Just use something like

```
when whatever my condition is [operatorid,Operator,,compares to] [value,Integer,,number]
```

And if you want to use `Decimal` macro instead of `Integer`, you can read my blog post [Sitecore Rules Engine - decimal macro](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-rules-engine-decimal-floating-point-number-macro).